# Relational database design - splitting tables

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I need to split a table, I think, because some records are related to one table and other records related to another table. But do I really need to split the table up?

The tables are as follows:

SAMPLE (**sample_id**, sample_type, borehole_id)
BOREHOLE (**borehole_id**, x, y, z)
TRAM (**drawpoint_id**, **section_id**)

Where the table SAMPLE has samples of type *core* and *tram*. Core samples are related to the BOREHOLE table and tram samples to the TRAM table. (Tram samples don't have geographical coordinates so need to be kept separately)

Other than that split in type the sample data is identical, in fact we can't separate the samples by type on input from the assay lab. We might get sample data from the lab all in one report and will only know what type they are after querying the type. I was hoping to store all SAMPLE assay results in one table.

How is this normally handled?

Comment: This is a faq, google 'stackoverflow philipxy faq subtype'.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I looked up subtypes and supertypes and this is it.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is identical then the design od table SAMPLE is wrong. 
I probably dont understant what you are trying to achieve, but the table SAMPLE needs only a couple of fields id_sample and title (or name), then youll need a table for storing these samples listings, say LIST table. 
Table LIST would have fields id_list, id_sample, id_borehole, date_rcvd, etc (whatever  fields you need to keep information about specific sample with its characteristcs)
Its not clear to me what the table TRAM should store, but it seems that you are repeating two columns from it to the SAMPLE table which is wrong.

Comment: Oops, yes that's a typo. I edited the post, though to make things clear for other readers. So tram has a composite key and some other info. Thanks for setting my mind in the right direction, I just couldn't see it. I am stuck in thinking of this data in a specific way. So if I had 2 tables BH_SAMPLE(sample_id, sample_type,borehole_id) and TRAM_SAMPLE(sample_id, sample_type,foreign-key) that would work. I can still keep the assay results in the table SAMPLE(sample_id, au_result).